# Custom input box styling in react-native-elements

Tags: react-native

Being new to react-native, I am trying to style my [input](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/input.html#inputcontainerstyle) fields using react-native-elements to look similar to their example ones ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmZsc.jpg)).

Even after going through the [source code](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements) for the example I still can't seem to figure out where I would start when it comes to customizing these fields to that extent.

Comment: What have you tried ? Nobody can't help you if you don't show us some code.

Comment: Maybe I should have worded it differently, but my code for the Input sections works well. I am more asking this to get an idea of where to start when it comes to making a custom looking input field (as seen in the picture), as I cannot seem to find anything relating to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a heads up for anyone else looking to do the same thing, I ended up using [this library](https://github.com/halilb/react-native-textinput-effects) to make nicer looking animated input fields. It isn't quite the same as what I had originally planned, but if you're in the same scenario as I was, I definitely recommend taking a look.